# Get defaultValues in useFieldArray from react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have an edit form where my user can edit the previous value saved.
I also add new input in the edit form as "SummaryOfChanges" who did not exist at the creation of the form.

Here, I would like to add a “default Value” in the SummaryOfChanges.
If the user saved a first time and edit again, it should show the “default value” and the last "SummaryOfChanges" add.

Problem here :

My default value return nothing. I don't have an error in my console. I would like to see the “default value”.

Here in the parent, my default Value :

```
const {
    register,
    control,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    reset,
    errors,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      SummaryOfChanges: [
        {
          message: 'message',
          date: "moment().format('LL')",
          UpdatedBy: 'userName',
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

Here is my child who contain my input SummaryOfChanges

```
export const SummaryOfChanges = ({ control, register, watch }) => {

  const moment = require('moment');
  const userName = useSelector((state) => state.users?.graphData?.displayName);

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'SummaryOfChanges',
  });

 
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Summary of Changes</label>
      <div>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="caption table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell> Summary</TableCell>
                <TableCell> Date </TableCell>
                <TableCell> Updated By</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>

            <TableBody>
              {fields?.map((item, index) => {
                const fieldName = `SummaryOfChanges[${index}]`;
                return (
                  <TableRow key={item.id}>
                    <TableCell>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        {...register(`${fieldName}.message`)}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <input
                        disabled
                        type="text"
                        {...register(`${fieldName}.date`)}
                      />
                    </TableCell>

                    <TableCell>
                      <input
                        disabled
                        type="text"
                        {...register(`${fieldName}.UpdatedBy`)}
                      />
                    </TableCell>

                    <TableCell>
                      <Button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => remove(index)}
                      >
                        x
                      </Button>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <br />
        <section>
          <Button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              append({
                date: moment().format('LL'),
                message: '',
                UpdatedBy: userName,
              });
            }}
          >
            +
          </Button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How to show the default value ?

I have already tried to do something with this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-defaultvalues-forked-znch0?file=/src/index.js
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved : I have set de default values in my child component and removed the Table.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export const SummaryOfChanges = () => {

  const userName = useSelector((state) => state.users?.graphData?.displayName);
  const moment = require('moment');
  const { register, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      SummaryOfChanges: [
        {
          message: ' ',
          date: moment().format('LL'),
          UpdatedBy: userName,
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'SummaryOfChanges',
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Summary of Changes</label>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li> Summary</li>
          <li> Date </li>
          <li> Updated By</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => {
            const fieldName = `SummaryOfChanges[${index}]`;
            return (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <input
                  name={`${fieldName}.message`}
                  defaultValue={`${item.message}`}  
                  {...register(`${fieldName}.message`)}
                />
                <input
                  name={`${fieldName}.date`}
                  defaultValue={`${item.date}`}  
                  {...register(`${fieldName}.date`)}
                /> 
                <input
                  name={`${fieldName}.UpdatedBy`}
                  defaultValue={`${item.UpdatedBy}`}  
                  {...register(`${fieldName}.UpdatedBy`)}
                />
                <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                  Delete
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <br />
        <section>
          <Button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              append({
                date: moment().format('LL'),
                message: '',
                UpdatedBy: userName,
              });
            }}
          >
            +
          </Button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```